# flutter send email attachment

Tags: file, email, flutter

My flutter app is using flutter_mailer: ^0.1.0 to send email. It is working well without attachment. But If I add the `attachments: [ x.path ]`,

- for IOS the app will quit immediately when I press the button.
- for Android the app will not open email application when I press the button.
  Please kindly help to solve this issue.

here with the print out of console of Android:

```
I/flutter ( 8933): /data/user/0/com.gph.testmanual/app_flutter/data.txt
I/fl      ( 8933): [/data/user/0/com.gph.testmanual/app_flutter/data.txt]
E/MethodChannel#flutter_mailer( 8933): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter_mailer( 8933): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.gph.testmanual/app_flutter/data.txt
```

here with the print out of console of IOS:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
Installing and launching...
Syncing files to device iPhone...
flutter: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D87ECFEF-A989-345D-AE543C-1CE5AF96546345F52/Documents/data.txt
```

My code:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  File x;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    writeData('Hello, How are you?').then((value) {
      x = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Read/Write'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      body: new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.4),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child:
              FlatButton(onPressed: () => _sendEmail(), child: Text("Button"))),
    );
  }

  void _sendEmail() async {
    debugPrint(x.path);
    final MailOptions mailOptions = MailOptions(
      body: 'a long body for the email',
      subject: 'Booking',
      recipients: ['gph.payment@gmail.com'],
      isHTML: false,
//      bccRecipients: ['other@example.com'],
//      ccRecipients: ['third@example.com'],
//      attachments: [ x.path ],
    );

    await FlutterMailer.send(mailOptions);
  }
}

Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path; //home/directory/
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;

  return new File('$path/data.txt'); //home/directory/data.txt
}

//Write and Read from our file
Future<File> writeData(String message) async {
  final file = await _localFile;

  //write to file
  return file.writeAsString('$message');
}

Future<String> readData() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;

    //Read
    String data = await file.readAsString();

    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return "Nothing saved yet!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be app documents directory — for some reason, the extension can't share from that yet. (Just reported a [bug for that](https://github.com/taljacobson/flutter_mailer/issues/10).)

My workaround is to copy the file under the temporary directory and attach it from there.